# how to fix fatal error - Class 'User' not found in php

Tags: php

This is user class.

```
<?php
class User {
    /* 
     *public static function get_all_users()
     */
    public function get_all_users() {
        global $link;
        $result_set = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `user`");
        return $result_set;
    }
}
```

Above class is user class i made object but cannot access. Display all use page of html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Admin Panel ::: </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Users :</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>S.N</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th colspan="2">Option</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            $user = new User();
            $result_set = $user->get_all_users();
            /* 
             *$result_set = User :: get_all_users(); - accessing user class using static keyword.
             */
            $i = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Contact']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
            <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>                                           
        <?php 
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not access user class when I create object of user class and user class is inside includes folder and below HTML file is inside admin folder or `admin ->viewuser.php` and `admin->includes->user.php` it gives error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include that User class inside the viewuser.php script !

```
include_once("includes/user.php");
```

I am not sure organizing your folders like that is the best way to do but it should work.

Comment: It might be worth it to mention namespacing as better form.